# Removing duplicates based on common and different in values

Tags: r, duplicates, data.table

I have a data table like this

```
dt <- data.table(date=c('d1','d2','d3','d1','d2','d3'),v1=c('a','a','b','a','b','b'),v2=c(2,2,4,2,4,4))
   date v1 v2
1:   d1  a  2
2:   d2  a  2 <-need to remove this 
3:   d3  b  4 
4:   d1  a  2
5:   d2  b  4 <-need to remove this 
6:   d3  b  4
```

My actual data contains 16million rows and 5 columns which make up the unique condition, and one date column. I want to remove duplicates that have the same common values(in v1,v2) but only when their dates(date) are different.

**Sample output**

```
   date v1 v2
1:   d1  a  2
2:   d3  b  4
3:   d1  a  2
4:   d3  b  4
```

I tried "duplicated" function but unable to find the right method to remove duplicates. Appreciate any help.

Comment: I actually don't understand the rule you want to identify duplicates by. Why you want to keep both rows 1 and 4 when they're identical?

Comment: I want to keep them because they have the same date.

Comment: @pauljeba could you please clarify what you'd like to do for rows with the same date but different v1/v2 values? for example, what would be the desired output for `dt <- data.table(date=c('d1','d2','d3','d1','d2','d3', 'd4', 'd4'), v1=c('a','a','b','a','b','b', 'a', 'b'),v2=c(2,2,4,2,4,4, 1, 2))` ?

Comment: @cath then those records should be persisted. The sample output for your testset here would be; `data.table(date=c('d1','d3','d1','d3', 'd4', 'd4'), v1=c('a','b','a','b', 'a', 'b'),v2=c(2,4,2,4, 1, 2))`

Comment: thanks for your clarification. Then @Jaap's solution and mine both give the desired output

Comment: @akrun no need to delete your answer: it shows a nice alternative method which worked for the original question

Comment: @akrun I was only concerned with the desired behaviour for not duplicated values. you don't need to delete your answer, I'm sure you can slightly modify it to make it totally right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I "translate" correctly, you need either the rows that are not duplicated for variables `v1` and `v2` or the rows that are duplicated for those variables but also for variable `date`

```
dt[!duplicated(dt[, .(v1, v2)]) | 
   (duplicated(dt[, .(v1, v2)]) & duplicated(dt[, .(date, v1, v2)]))]
#   date v1 v2
#1:   d1  a  2
#2:   d3  b  4
#3:   d1  a  2
#4:   d3  b  4
```

As mentionned by @Arun, another preferable way, to avoid making a copy of `dt`, is to take advantage of `by` parameter of `duplicated.data.table`:

```
dt[!duplicated(dt, by=c("v1", "v2")) | 
   (duplicated(dt, by=c("v1", "v2")) & duplicated(dt, by=c("date", "v1", "v2")))]
```

Comment: thanks @akrun, I just have a doubt your solution does what is expected: it retains the good duplicated, that's for sure, but (unless I'm missing something), fails to retain the not duplicated values, for same date. (you can have a look at the comment I posted under the Q)

Comment: I understand your concern.  With a simple example, it is not easy to know what the OP expects.  As we speak, there is another interpretation of the question (though it got a plus vote)

Comment: Thank you @Cath! Nice work in clearly articulating the logical conditions I needed.

Comment: `duplicated.data.table` has a `by` argument. The `.(v1,v2)` returns a copy.

Comment: thanks @Arun, so `dt[!duplicated(dt, by=c("v1", "v2")) | (duplicated(dt, by=c("v1", "v2")) & duplicated(dt, by=c("date", "v1", "v2")))]` should do the same without copying the table ?

Answer (score 4):

The way I understood the question is that for each `v1`/`v2` combination only the dates with the highest number of occurences need to be preserved. To achieve that you could do:

```
dt[, n:=.N, by = .(date,v1,v2)][, .SD[n==max(n)], by = .(v1,v2)][, n:= NULL][]
```

which gives:

```
   v1 v2 date
1:  a  2   d1
2:  a  2   d1
3:  b  4   d3
4:  b  4   d3
```

With the provided example data this gives the same result as @Cath and @Akrun.

---

However, with the following data (posted by @Cath in the comments of the question):

```
dt1 <- data.table(date=c('d1','d2','d3','d1','d2','d3','d4','d4'), 
                  v1=c('a','a','b','a','b','b','a','b'),
                  v2=c(2,2,4,2,4,4,1,2))
```

Now @akrun's method will give a different result:

```
> dt1[!duplicated(dt1[, .(v1, v2)]) | (duplicated(dt1[, .(v1, v2)]) & duplicated(dt1[, .(date, v1, v2)])), ]
   date v1 v2
1:   d1  a  2
2:   d3  b  4
3:   d1  a  2
4:   d3  b  4
5:   d4  a  1
6:   d4  b  2
> dt1[, if(uniqueN(.SD, by = c('v1', 'v2'))==1) .SD ,by = date]
   date v1 v2
1:   d1  a  2
2:   d1  a  2
3:   d3  b  4
4:   d3  b  4
> dt1[, n:=.N, by = .(date,v1,v2)][, .SD[n==max(n)], by = .(v1,v2)][, n:= NULL][]
   v1 v2 date
1:  a  2   d1
2:  a  2   d1
3:  b  4   d3
4:  b  4   d3
5:  a  1   d4
6:  b  2   d4
```

Some clearer direction about what OP wants are therefore welcome.